# How to stop "aptd" from maxing out my CPU?

Tags: 11.10, cpu-load

After running the "top" command in the terminal, I see "aptd" running which causes the cpu to run at 100%. If I'm updating the system, or installing a software, I see it. I only recently noticed it. Is there anyway to stop it or tell me what is its function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`aptd` is the service that installs software for Ubuntu Software Center and Update Manager.  It runs as a separate, background process so that the installer can have root privileges while the GUI runs under your own user ID.

You should not stop `aptd` while software is installing: killing it will interrupt the installation, and possibly break the package system.

If you are *not* installing software and still see `aptd` using CPU time, then it's likely that you have the system set to automatically check for updates; those automatic update checks also use `aptd`.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the above information, if you notice that it is running for a *long* time - say an hour or more, it may be necessary to kill it.  I ran into that when the Synaptic Package Manager appeared to be not responding for an extended period of time.  After force closing it from the GUI, I found a couple instances of aptd and several other related processes running, and eventually I had to kill them.

In my case, I found that it was necessary to run the following commands to recover:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: I tried running sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a and it is just hanging there waiting to complete. Any thoughts?

Comment: `-a` is an unknown option for dpkg-reconfigure in Ubuntu 20.04