# CPU 100% Usage with aptd (python3)? How do I resolve this process issue?

Tags: apt, cpu-load, aptdaemon

I've been having this happen for a while - not too sure what caused it.

[image]

There's one or two processes (here `/usr/sbin/aptd`) that always spike up to 98-100% CPU usage, and I'm not sure how to solve this.

Would someone mind clarifying what the issue is, and if uninstalling Python 2.7 (and dependencies, i.e. Python 3, etc.) would help?

Thanks.

Edit: `sudo apt-get update` gives me the following errors:

```
david@david-Blade:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
david@david-Blade:~$  sudo apt-get -y update
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

**Update 1:**

Tried running `sudo killall -9 apt-get` and `sudo kill -9 _pid_` as per instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/589840/help-aptd-is-maxing-out-my-cpu) and it appears that I'm unable to do so? Consequently, dpkg is blocked by another process and I can't run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a` or `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

```
david@david-Blade:~$ sudo killall -9 apt-get
apt-get: no process found
david@david-Blade:~$ sudo kill -9 _pid_ 
kill: failed to parse argument: '_pid_'
```

**Update 2:**

Ran 'sudo dkpg --configure -a' and disabled my UEFI booter. Running `sudo apt-get update` gives me the following error log:

```
david@david-Blade:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bsdtar libgsoap8 libmuparser2v5 libqt4-opengl libvncserver1 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-42-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-42-generic linux-tools-4.4.0-42
  linux-tools-4.4.0-42-generic python3-blinker python3-cffi-backend python3-cryptography python3-dateutil
  python3-idna python3-jwt python3-oauthlib python3-requests-oauthlib python3-tz ruby-childprocess ruby-domain-name
  ruby-erubis ruby-ffi ruby-http-cookie ruby-i18n ruby-listen ruby-log4r ruby-mime-types ruby-net-scp ruby-net-sftp
  ruby-net-ssh ruby-netrc ruby-nokogiri ruby-rb-inotify ruby-rest-client ruby-sqlite3 ruby-unf ruby-unf-ext sqlite3
  thunderbird-locale-en thunderbird-locale-en-gb thunderbird-locale-en-us virtualbox-dkms
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apparmor base-files distro-info-data dkms gnome-software gnome-software-common google-chrome-stable im-config
  initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin initramfs-tools-core language-pack-en language-pack-gnome-en libapparmor-perl
  libapparmor1 libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6:i386 libc6-dbg libc6-dev libc6-i386 libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5
  libqt5gui5 libqt5network5 libqt5opengl5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5widgets5 libqt5xml5
  libwhoopsie0 locales macbuntu-os-icons-lts-v7 macbuntu-os-ithemes-lts-v7 multiarch-support python3-distupgrade
  python3-update-manager r-base r-base-core r-base-dev r-base-html r-cran-cluster r-cran-codetools r-doc-html
  r-recommended snapd ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk unattended-upgrades update-manager
  update-manager-core update-notifier update-notifier-common virtualbox-5.1 whoopsie
57 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 192 MB of archives.
After this operation, 865 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 google-chrome-stable amd64 54.0.2840.90-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2607:f8b0:4009:812::200e 80]
Get:2 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ r-base-core 3.3.2-1xenial0 [21.0 MB]                          
Ign:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/macbuntu/ubuntu xenial/main i386 macbuntu-os-icons-lts-v7 all 3.18.7~xenial~NoobsLab.com
Get:4 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 base-files amd64 9.4ubuntu4.3 [67.7 kB]
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/macbuntu/ubuntu xenial/main i386 macbuntu-os-ithemes-lts-v7 all 3.18.7~xenial~NoobsLab.com
Err:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/macbuntu/ubuntu xenial/main i386 macbuntu-os-icons-lts-v7 all 3.18.7~xenial~NoobsLab.com
  404  Not Found
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/macbuntu/ubuntu xenial/main i386 macbuntu-os-ithemes-lts-v7 all 3.18.7~xenial~NoobsLab.com
  404  Not Found
Get:6 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial/contrib amd64 virtualbox-5.1 amd64 5.1.8-111374~Ubuntu~xenial [65.2 MB]
Err:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libc6-i386 amd64 2.23-0ubuntu4           
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Err:8 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libc6-dev amd64 2.23-0ubuntu4
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Err:9 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libc-dev-bin amd64 2.23-0ubuntu4
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Err:10 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libc6-dbg amd64 2.23-0ubuntu4
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Err:11 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libc6 amd64 2.23-0ubuntu4
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Err:12 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 libc6 i386 2.23-0ubuntu4
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Ign:13 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 locales all 2.23-0ubuntu4  
Err:14 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libc-bin amd64 2.23-0ubuntu4
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Get:15 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 language-pack-en all 1:16.04+20161009 [145 kB]
Get:16 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 language-pack-gnome-en all 1:16.04+20161009 [169 kB]
Ign:17 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk all 1:16.04.17       
Ign:18 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core all 1:16.04.17
Ign:19 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 python3-distupgrade all 1:16.04.17
Get:20 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 update-manager all 1:16.04.4 [543 kB]
Get:21 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ r-cran-cluster 2.0.5-1xenial0 [490 kB]                       
Get:22 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ r-cran-codetools 0.2-15-1cran1xenial0 [45.0 kB]            
Get:23 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ r-base 3.3.2-1xenial0 [40.4 kB]                              
Get:24 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ r-recommended 3.3.2-1xenial0 [2,708 B]                   
Get:25 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ r-base-dev 3.3.2-1xenial0 [4,306 B]                          
Get:26 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ r-doc-html 3.3.2-1xenial0 [547 kB]                           
Get:27 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ r-base-html 3.3.2-1xenial0 [85.7 kB]                       
Get:28 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 update-manager-core all 1:16.04.4 [5,332 B]     
Get:29 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 python3-update-manager all 1:16.04.4 [31.5 kB]
Get:30 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 update-notifier amd64 3.168.2 [48.2 kB]
Get:31 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 update-notifier-common all 3.168.2 [163 kB]
Get:32 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libqt5core5a amd64 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 [1,817 kB]
Get:33 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libqt5dbus5 amd64 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 [175 kB]
Get:34 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libqt5network5 amd64 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 [540 kB]
Get:35 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libqt5gui5 amd64 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 [2,287 kB]
Get:36 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libqt5widgets5 amd64 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 [2,253 kB]
Get:37 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libqt5opengl5 amd64 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 [128 kB]
Get:38 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libqt5printsupport5 amd64 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 [174 kB]
Get:39 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 whoopsie amd64 0.2.52.2 [22.7 kB]               
Get:40 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libwhoopsie0 amd64 0.2.52.2 [9,898 B]           
Get:41 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libapparmor1 amd64 2.10.95-0ubuntu2.5 [31.6 kB] 
Err:42 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 multiarch-support amd64 2.23-0ubuntu4           
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Get:43 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 distro-info-data all 0.28ubuntu0.2 [4,006 B]    
Ign:44 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 initramfs-tools all 0.122ubuntu8.5               
Ign:45 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 initramfs-tools-core all 0.122ubuntu8.5          
Err:46 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 initramfs-tools-bin amd64 0.122ubuntu8.5        
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Get:47 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libapparmor-perl amd64 2.10.95-0ubuntu2.5 [31.4 kB]
Get:48 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 apparmor amd64 2.10.95-0ubuntu2.5 [446 kB]      
Get:49 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 dkms all 2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.3 [66.1 kB]          
Err:50 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 gnome-software amd64 3.20.1+git20160923.2.7374bdc-0ubuntu1~xenial1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Ign:51 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 gnome-software-common all 3.20.1+git20160923.2.7374bdc-0ubuntu1~xenial1
Ign:52 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 im-config all 0.29-1ubuntu12.2                   
Get:53 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libqt5sql5 amd64 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 [104 kB]
Get:54 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libqt5sql5-sqlite amd64 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 [33.1 kB]
Get:55 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libqt5xml5 amd64 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 [91.9 kB]
Err:56 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 snapd amd64 2.16ubuntu3                         
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Ign:57 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 unattended-upgrades all 0.90ubuntu0.1            
Err:13 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 locales all 2.23-0ubuntu4                        
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Err:17 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk all 1:16.04.17       
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Err:18 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core all 1:16.04.17      
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Err:19 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 python3-distupgrade all 1:16.04.17               
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Err:44 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 initramfs-tools all 0.122ubuntu8.5               
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Err:45 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 initramfs-tools-core all 0.122ubuntu8.5          
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Err:51 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 gnome-software-common all 3.20.1+git20160923.2.7374bdc-0ubuntu1~xenial1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Err:52 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 im-config all 0.29-1ubuntu12.2                   
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Err:57 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 unattended-upgrades all 0.90ubuntu0.1            
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Fetched 96.9 MB in 12s (7,565 kB/s)                                                                                  
E: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6-i386_2.23-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6-dev_2.23-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc-dev-bin_2.23-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6-dbg_2.23-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6_2.23-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6_2.23-0ubuntu4_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/locales_2.23-0ubuntu4_all.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc-bin_2.23-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_54.0.2840.90-1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 2607:f8b0:4009:812::200e 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-release-upgrader/ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk_16.04.17_all.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-release-upgrader/ubuntu-release-upgrader-core_16.04.17_all.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-release-upgrader/python3-distupgrade_16.04.17_all.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.23-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/initramfs-tools/initramfs-tools_0.122ubuntu8.5_all.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/initramfs-tools/initramfs-tools-core_0.122ubuntu8.5_all.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/initramfs-tools/initramfs-tools-bin_0.122ubuntu8.5_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-software/gnome-software_3.20.1+git20160923.2.7374bdc-0ubuntu1~xenial1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-software/gnome-software-common_3.20.1+git20160923.2.7374bdc-0ubuntu1~xenial1_all.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/im-config/im-config_0.29-1ubuntu12.2_all.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/snapd/snapd_2.16ubuntu3_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades_0.90ubuntu0.1_all.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/macbuntu/ubuntu/pool/main/m/macbuntu-os-icons-lts-v7/macbuntu-os-icons-lts-v7_3.18.7~xenial~NoobsLab.com_all.deb 404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/macbuntu/ubuntu/pool/main/m/macbuntu-os-ithemes-lts-v7/macbuntu-os-ithemes-lts-v7_3.18.7~xenial~NoobsLab.com_all.deb 404  Not Found

E: Unable to fetch some archives, try running apt-get update or apt-get --fix-missing.
```

Comment: Uninstalling python, either 2 or 3, will make your system unusable.

Comment: NEVER uninstall Python, neither 2 or 3! Many system applications (`apt` for example) are written in Python and will stop working if you break your Python installations.

Comment: Well, bollocks... Alright - I sort of had the inkling that uninstalling was a bad idea. Any idea why Python 3 is causing this abnormally high CPU load? @ByteCommander

Comment: It is not Python's fault. Python3 is just the interpreter that runs the `/usr/sbin/aptd` scriipt, which is apt-daemon. Has something to do with your package management and automatic updates, I guess. Check the output of `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` for errors or warnings.

Comment: This: http://askubuntu.com/questions/589840/help-aptd-is-maxing-out-my-cpu and http://askubuntu.com/questions/75308/how-to-stop-aptd-from-maxing-out-my-cpu/173537#173537 seems relevant

Comment: @ByteCommander I've updated my OP with the error logs that I get. My problem looks similar to the threads Jacob has linked to. I'm relatively new to Ubuntu and have been told not to blindly copy terminal commands, so I'm wondering how I should progress, and if I should attempt using 'sudo killall -9 apt-get' and 'sudo kill -9 _pid_ ' from here. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for editing. You are completely right about not blindly running sudo commands. Older posts from AU are less risky however. If they were incorrect and/or dangerous, in most cases they would be heavily downvoted and/or commented on. It looks like the attempt to update is never ending because the process is locked forever.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for the future, thanks. I've updated the original post. I'm unable to kill the apt-get or aptd processes for some reason. The post you suggested following was talking about an issue with Ubuntu 12.04 - not sure if that plays into this situation?

Comment: Probably you should try `sudo killall aptd`?

Comment: @ByteCommander Worked - but I'm unable to run `sudo killall apt-get` (no process found).  Same errors with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh` and `sudo dpkg --configure`.

Comment: What do you mean by "same errors"? Those "unable to lock" ones? Either you still have some package manager process running or the one you have killed could not remove its lock before dying. Not sure what the best way to proceed would be...

Comment: @ByteCommander Ah, ok so I was able to run `sudo dkpg --configure -a` and  it seems like my UEFI Booter was the problem. I've disabled it for now, and I was able to run the command properly. After trying to run `sudo apt-get update`, I get an error log (which I'll post shortly in my OP).

Comment: You should disable the failing PPAs for now and switch from your local mirror to the main Ubuntu repository server in your "System Settings > Software & Updates". After that, try again.

Comment: Looks like the problem's been solved for now (might have to do a couple more checks before I know for sure)! `sudo apt-get update` still gives me a few errors, but they're just archives that can't be fetched. This is even after I switch to the main Ubuntu repo. CPU usage  across all tasks looking normal though. Thanks a lot for all the help!